# Apache2 mod_autoindex IndexStyleSheet Directive not applying CSS within mod_userdir directories

Tags: apache-2.4, debian-bullseye

I am using mod_userdir to share files using mod_autoindex to generate a directory index for people to browse and access them, and due to the retina burning nature of the default CSS I wish to rework the CSS to something darker. While I can do this with my README for each page, I would prefer to not need to include a README for each directory.

This is the css I used for style in my `README.html`, where it works fine, and what I copy pasted it into a `style.css` file.

```css
body {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}

a:link {
    color: green;
}

a:visited {
    color: yellow;
}

a:hover {
    color: red;
}

a:active {
    color: red;
}
```

And here is my `.htaccess` file contents.

```
IndexOptions FancyIndexing HTMLTable FoldersFirst IgnoreCase SuppressDescription SuppressHTMLPreamble SuppressLastModified VersionSort SuppressColumnSorting IconsAreLinks NameWidth=30
IndexStyleSheet "/style.css"
```

I have tried putting an absolute path to my `style.css` as `IndexStyleSheet "/home/user/public_html"`. I have also tried moving the file to `/home/user/public_html/css`  and copying the example from the documentation found here: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_autoindex.html#indexstylesheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I FINALLY solved it myself and will include the solution for anyone who has this issue in the future:

In `.htaccess` I made the following change:

Line 2 `IndexStyleSheet "/style.css"`  changed to `IndexStyleSheet "/~<username>/style.css"`